# Model Inheritance in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, inheritance, associations

I have a class `Item` and another `Weapon`. They share a lot of the same state (e.g. `size`, `value`), but `Weapon` has some extra stuff, like `damage`, `critical`, and `threat`. In raw Ruby, I’d extract these common attributes to a module and compose both of them, or I might subclass `Weapon` from `Item` and put the common state in the superclass.

Except I’m using Rails. Single-Table Inheritance doesn’t seem like a nice solution as `Weapon` has a number of attributes not in `Item`, and I don’t fancy all the empty DB columns. Polymorphic association doesn’t right either, as it seems to be more useful for sharing associations between models, rather than sharing state. Using a Concern: much the same issue.

Is there anything in Rails that allows me to extend the state of a single model in another, while building an extra table for any additional attributes?

Here's a code example of what I'd like in raw Ruby:

```
class Item
  attr_accessor :value, :weight, item_type 

class Weapon < Item
  attr_accessor :damage, :threat, :critical, :weapon_type

Weapon.new(value: 12) # => weapon instance with value 12
```

In Rails, can try adding `item_id` to `Weapon` - but then I can't do `Weapon.new(value: 12)`, I'd have to do `Weapon.new(item: Item.new(value: 12))`.

Comment: the above models you have created are absolutely fine. You can call `Weapon.new(value: 12)`  and `Item.new(value: 12)`

Comment: Yes, in Ruby. Not in Rails, without using STI, and leaving loads of blank DB columns in the `items` table.

Comment: There is no easy way to do inheritance when you have to talk to databases, I also can't see what benefits you get from inheritance here, even if it was possible what would you call the table in the database, I think leaving the models separate is fine, and would make the codebase less confusing

Comment: Because `Weapon` is a clear OOP subclass of `Item`. They'll also share behaviour. Should I also have separate models for `Potion` and `Gem` and `Furniture`, and so on? I would prefer to have common state aspects, like `value`, `weight`, etc., in a single place.

Comment: OOP is not an end, it is an means and with the way Rails works not all concepts of OOP can apply, if you try to force inheritance into this, you might end up with code that is difficult to maintain

Comment: So you're saying I *should* have separate tables for every possible kind of object (i.e.: potentially hundreds, with thousands of lines of duplicated code describing identical behaviour) with slightly differing state? That doesn't sound reasonable.

Comment: Can your Weapon class have a "has_one" relationship with a new model (i.e., another table in your database)?  That way Item wouldn't be involved, you could still use STI but your Weapon class could be extended by the second model?  With  some scopes and classes, the second model would feel like part of Weapon?

Comment: That makes sense if I were saying `Weapon` had subclasses, but I'm not really talking about subclassing `Weapon` here - I'm saying that `Weapon` has a superclass, `Item`, which is shared with other classes, like `Gem` or `Potion` or `Furniture`. I'm having some luck with [this article on Multiple Table Inheritance](http://dan.chak.org/enterprise-rails/chapter-10-multiple-table-inheritance/): if it works I'll update this post :)

Comment: @SamJames I don't see any benefit to making `Item` a superclass of all models. Its like creating a `Thing` table and having all my models inherit it because they're all `things` -- you're taking a theoretical concept to an extreme beyond any practical usage. Moreover, it will not work with how ActiveRecord is designed because ActiveRecord is built as an ORM for relational databases, so it must represent the database first and foremost. Databases have no concept of OOP inheritance.

Comment: Yep, I think I'm just going to use separate tables. It's occurred to me that this way of doing things actually violates Liskov Substitution, too.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR this violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), so I shouldn't do it.**

According to Liskov, object subtypes should be interchangeable - that is, a method that uses an instance of the `Weapon` class should work if I switch the `Weapon` for a `Potion` or a `Gem`. Clearly, that's not the case: so from an OOP angle, I shouldn't be using Inheritance here.

Thanks for the debate!